# How to Render Prose Diffs from Git Patches?

Tags: git, opendocument

What would be the best approach to emulate Github's [rendered prose diffs](https://github.blog/2014-02-14-rendered-prose-diffs/) using the out put from `git diff` as described in [here](https://www.nickcoding.com/2014/10/30/making-git-prose-friendly/)?

In other words, how do I take the git patch output and render it like with html or possibly Open Document XML?